# rails js.erb does not get rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following code in edit.html.erb

```
    <%= f.select(:newpages, @pages, { :include_blank => 'No newpage' }, :id => 'function', :multiple => true, :size => '7', :selected => @selected ) %>
```

and i have another code which is using [jquery-multiselect](http://www.loudev.com) in edit.js.erb, but it does not get rendered.

```
$('#function').multiSelect()
```

I had gone through the railcasts tutorial and followed the instructions but i could not understand why it doesn't work.

My controller looks like this: (i have not format it to js)

```
  def edit
    @print = Print.find(params[:id])
 #   @print.blackwhites.build
    @pages = (1..(@print.number_of_images_entry)).to_a
  end
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your JS console?

Comment: I got ReferenceError: $ not defined

Answer (score 0):

It seems like for some reason JQuery is not known in this time of parsing and so the $ sign is unknown

1. make sure you are using the
   gem 'jquery-rails'
   in your gem file
2. make sure to include
   //= require jquery
   in your application.js

Hope it will help

Comment: I have the jquery-rails in my Gemfile and //=require jquery before this but it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

From the source, i saw the jquery loaded after the erb has loaded.

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193905/jquery-not-working-on-rails-3-2-8

No errors now but my jquery function doesn't work eventhough i see it is loading.