# jQuery is not loading, how jquery-rails works

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am learning jquery & ajax via railscasts[136 revise jquery & ajax](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised). I spent more than 4 hours still can not make the first step work.

The problem is I add `remote: true` as data attribute and `new.js.erb` under `app/view/task`. However, It never triggers the ajax call. It just redirects to the new page.

Since It just really simple. I create public repo. [here](https://github.com/nyrails/jquery_ajax)

Then, after several hours research, I found the jQuery is not been loaded. Because, I added

```
debugger
if (jQuery) {
  alert('Jquery is loaded')
} else {
  alert ('Jquery is not loaded')
}
```

You can also find that in the github repo. I also read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193905/jquery-not-working-on-rails-3-2-8), and also tried to switch the `ujs` and `jquery`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

or `css` and `js`.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

to:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
```

nothing works.

1. I want to know, how jquery-rails works. Why there is no error and it just can not load jQuery?
2. I tried to upgrade rails version 3.2.8 to 3.2.15, which turn out to work. Still would like to know the reason.

Wired issue, Would like to figure out the reason. Thanks

Comment: Your repo on 3.2.8 works fine.  I didn't change a thing, just ran bundle install, your notifications of jquery being loaded are appearing, and `new` is processing as js instead of html as expected and the form is being added to the page without a reload.  My guess is that when you updated your version of rails you fixed something that was amiss in your bundled gems.  Since a clean bundle works, that is all I can imagine.

Comment: OFF TOPIC: you should upgrade to 3.2.15 there are serious security issues before 3.2.13, just update the rails version in the Gemfile and run `bundle update rails`

Comment: Thanks @trh please move your explanation to an answer, I will accept it. Since, that exactly the problem. I use rvm to maintain gem set, which probably the problem. And the wired part is there is no proper error for that, if it can not find the `jquery-rails` gems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comments: the problem seems to be with the bundle itself.

Github repo on 3.2.8 works fine.

Clone and run bundle install, your notifications of jquery being loaded are appearing, and new is processing as js instead of html as expected and the form is being added to the page without a reload.

Also per @house9 comment, please remember to update all rails 3.2 apps to at least 3.2.14 to fix major security flaw.